# Transform JSON map to an array in Postgres via update statement

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a postgresql table called `datasource` with jsonb column called `data`. It has the following structure:

```
{  
   "key1":{"param1" : "value1", "param2" : "value2"},
   "key2":{"param2_1" : "value2_1", "param2_2" : "value2_2"},
   "key3":{"param3_1" : "value3_1", "param3_2" : "value3_2"}  
}
```

Is there any way to write some UPDATE script to transform given JSON to the following:

```
[  
   {"key": "key1", "param1" : "value1", "param2" : "value2"},
   {"key": "key2", "param2_1" : "value2_1", "param2_2" : "value2_2"},
   {"key": "key3", "param3_1" : "value3_1", "param3_2" : "value3_2"}  
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unnest the object to rows in a lateral join, then aggregate back into an array:

```
select d.*, x.*
from datasource d
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('key', j.k) || j.v) new_data
    from jsonb_each(d.data) as j(k, v)
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a94eb9b89c54cf0027f12105aac0e20)** - with `jsonb_pretty()` enabled:

[image]

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update datasource d
set data = (
    select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('key', j.k) || j.v)
    from jsonb_each(d.data) as j(k, v)
)
```